# Unable to view First entry of serialized lists in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm storing a list of attacks on a serialized object for a particular character, like so:

[image]

However, when collapsing the first entry of the list, it seems to bug out and behaves incorrectly, seeping into the next elements. Other elements in the list work correctly as expected.

[image]

I've been noticing this pretty consistently when working w/ serialized objects that have a list or array field as part of their serialized data. I've tried both lists and arrays and the same things happens. I don't think this happened when I was on 2018, and mainly started happening since I switched to the 2021.3.xf series

Is there a known build that fixes this? or is there some attribute I need to set to signal Unity about the field?

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed a new build and it seems fixed in 2021.3.5f. Gonna mark this as the answer, it was a unity bug

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).